# How to disable iOS constraints?

Tags: ios, constraints

The most challenging platform for my app is iPhone4, because of limited space. I got it to work well using only frames; trying to use constraints was not fruitful.  iPhone5 and larger work fine with the added constraints.

My problem is disabling the constraints when my app sees itself running on iPhone4; calling `removeConstraints` is so far ineffective.  In fact, as a test, when there are *no* constraints in the storyboard, calling `removeConstraints`  *ruins* the layout; without that call the layout is fine.

I tried these, one at a time, and both:

```
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
[superview removeConstraints:superview.constraints];
```

What am I doing wrong in trying to disable all constraints?  Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Can you explain why using constraints was not fruitful (what problems did you have)? There's no reason you shouldn't be able to use constraints to make a view work correctly on a 3.5" and 4" screen.

Comment: If you added the constraints then you can set constraints like that so your app will work in both 3.5 inch and 4 inch screen. No need to remove constraints for iPhone 4.

Comment: I think the problem is my app simply doesn't fit iPhone 4, and the constraint engine won't let me have the overlapping item I need; I haven't found a way to force it (but no constraints works fine). So now a related question: Can I somehow specify only iPhone 5 and larger? This would seem to be a growing issue with 6 and 6 plus. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

If you have use autolayout cosnstrains ,and autolayout only available in iOS7.